# Implementing extension method WebRequest.GetResponseAsync with support for CancellationToken

Tags: .net, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, task-parallel-library, cancellation

The idea here is simple, but the implementation has some interesting nuances. This is the signature of the extension method I would like to implement in **.NET 4**.

```
public static Task<WebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this WebRequest request, CancellationToken token);
```

Here is my initial implementation. From what I've read, the web request might need to be [cancelled due to a timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx). In addition to the support described on that page, I want to properly call `request.Abort()` if cancellation is requested via the `CancellationToken`.

```
public static Task<WebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this WebRequest request, CancellationToken token)
{
    if (request == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

    return Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebRequest, CancellationToken, WebResponse>(BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, request, token, null);
}

private static IAsyncResult BeginGetResponse(WebRequest request, CancellationToken token, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(callback, state);
    if (!asyncResult.IsCompleted)
    {
        if (request.Timeout != Timeout.Infinite)
            ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle, WebRequestTimeoutCallback, request, request.Timeout, true);
        if (token != CancellationToken.None)
            ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(token.WaitHandle, WebRequestCancelledCallback, Tuple.Create(request, token), Timeout.Infinite, true);
    }

    return asyncResult;
}

private static void WebRequestTimeoutCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
{
    if (timedOut)
    {
        WebRequest request = state as WebRequest;
        if (request != null)
            request.Abort();
    }
}

private static void WebRequestCancelledCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
{
    Tuple<WebRequest, CancellationToken> data = state as Tuple<WebRequest, CancellationToken>;
    if (data != null && data.Item2.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        data.Item1.Abort();
    }
}
```

My question is simple yet challenging. Will this implementation actually behave as expected when used with the TPL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will this implementation actually behave as expected when used with the TPL?

No.

1. It will not flag the `Task<T>` result as cancelled, so the behavior will not be exactly as expected.
2. In the event of a timeout, the `WebException` contained in the `AggregateException` reported by `Task.Exception` will have the status `WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled`. It should instead be `WebExceptionStatus.Timeout`.

I would actually recommend using `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to implement this.  This allows you to write the code without making your own APM style methods:

```
public static Task<WebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this WebRequest request, CancellationToken token)
{
    if (request == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

    bool timeout = false;
    TaskCompletionSource<WebResponse> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<WebResponse>();

    AsyncCallback completedCallback =
        result =>
        {
            try
            {
                completionSource.TrySetResult(request.EndGetResponse(result));
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (timeout)
                    completionSource.TrySetException(new WebException("No response was received during the time-out period for a request.", WebExceptionStatus.Timeout));
                else if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    completionSource.TrySetCanceled();
                else
                    completionSource.TrySetException(ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                completionSource.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        };

    IAsyncResult asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(completedCallback, null);
    if (!asyncResult.IsCompleted)
    {
        if (request.Timeout != Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            WaitOrTimerCallback timedOutCallback =
                (object state, bool timedOut) =>
                {
                    if (timedOut)
                    {
                        timeout = true;
                        request.Abort();
                    }
                };

            ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle, timedOutCallback, null, request.Timeout, true);
        }

        if (token != CancellationToken.None)
        {
            WaitOrTimerCallback cancelledCallback =
                (object state, bool timedOut) =>
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        request.Abort();
                };

            ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(token.WaitHandle, cancelledCallback, null, Timeout.Infinite, true);
        }
    }

    return completionSource.Task;
}
```

The advantage here is that your `Task<T>` result will work fully as expected (will be flagged as canceled, or raise the same exception with timeout info as synchronous version, etc).  This also avoids the overhead of using `Task.Factory.FromAsync`, since you're already handling most of the difficult work involved there yourself.

---

**Addendum by 280Z28**

Here is a unit test showing proper operation for the method above.

```
[TestClass]
public class AsyncWebRequestTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAsyncWebRequest()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.com");
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        Task<WebResponse> response = request.GetResponseAsync();
        response.Wait();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAsyncWebRequestTimeout()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.com");
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Timeout = 0;
        Task<WebResponse> response = request.GetResponseAsync();
        try
        {
            response.Wait();
            Assert.Fail("Expected an exception");
        }
        catch (AggregateException exception)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(TaskStatus.Faulted, response.Status);

            ReadOnlyCollection<Exception> exceptions = exception.InnerExceptions;
            Assert.AreEqual(1, exceptions.Count);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(exceptions[0], typeof(WebException));

            WebException webException = (WebException)exceptions[0];
            Assert.AreEqual(WebExceptionStatus.Timeout, webException.Status);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAsyncWebRequestCancellation()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.com");
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task<WebResponse> response = request.GetResponseAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        try
        {
            response.Wait();
            Assert.Fail("Expected an exception");
        }
        catch (AggregateException exception)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(TaskStatus.Canceled, response.Status);

            ReadOnlyCollection<Exception> exceptions = exception.InnerExceptions;
            Assert.AreEqual(1, exceptions.Count);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(exceptions[0], typeof(OperationCanceledException));
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAsyncWebRequestError()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.com/fail");
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        Task<WebResponse> response = request.GetResponseAsync();
        try
        {
            response.Wait();
            Assert.Fail("Expected an exception");
        }
        catch (AggregateException exception)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(TaskStatus.Faulted, response.Status);

            ReadOnlyCollection<Exception> exceptions = exception.InnerExceptions;
            Assert.AreEqual(1, exceptions.Count);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(exceptions[0], typeof(WebException));

            WebException webException = (WebException)exceptions[0];
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ((HttpWebResponse)webException.Response).StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @280Z28 Thank - I wrote this without VS, so couldn't actually test it all ;)

Comment: @280Z28 Yeah - As I couldn'te test it, I didn't realize that `Abort` would still trigger the callback (makes sense that it does).  That will just cause the behavior to be a bit off, but still functional.  (You'll get an WebException instead of proper cancelation).

Comment: I edited your post to 1) properly describe the 2 major errors in my original question (including 1 new one), 2) contain the latest working code, and 3) contain a test class showing proper behavior under a success case and 3 different failure cases (cancellation, timeout, and a 404 error).

Comment: @280Z28 Thanks!  This looks like a reasonable, fully flushed out implementation now.

Comment: Thanks alot guys! One note though. Only one unittest is actually testing the new extension method. The other ones are just testing framework functionality, because they don't pass in a cancellationtoken.

Comment: After some further work, I realized that this answer does not properly use `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. The handling of the `RegisteredWaitHandle` objects returned by that method is critical for the long-term success of this method, in particular if a GC occurs while the web request is still active. Here is my modified implementation: https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/blob/a79c5a0e03a3648ea020e79a2120b1cb98f60df5/src/corelib/Core/WebRequestExtensions.cs#L34-L122