# Efficient resource usage in TPL continuations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, continuations

I'm interested in efficiently using system resources in conjunction with the Task Parallel Library and continuations.

Consider the following scenario which uses the [`GetResponseAsync()` extension method defined in another recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17494687/138304).

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
Task<WebResponse> responseTask = request.GetResponseAsync(cancellationToken);
Func<Task<WebResponse>, WebResponse> continuation =
    task =>
    {
        WebRequest followup = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri2);
        return followup.GetResponseAsync(cancellationToken).Result;
    };
Task<WebResponse> finalResultTask = responseTask.ContinueWith(continuation, cancellationToken);
```

There are multiple problems with this configuration, and I'm wondering how this can best be handled. The major items I've identified so far are:

1. The execution of the core of `responseTask` efficiently uses resources by not blocking a user thread during the asynchronous execution. However, since the continuation is defined as a `Func` lambda, the thread executing the continuation will block on the `return` line until the execution of the follow-up request is complete. A better situation would provide continuation-like behavior while not blocking a user thread.
2. The behavior of `responseTask` and `finalResultTask` differ in regards to cancellation. If operation is cancelled while `responseTask` is executing, `responseTask` will enter the state `TaskStatus.Canceled`. However, if the operation is canceled while `finalResultTask` is executing, the attempt to access the `Result` property will result in an exception, causing the task to enter the `TaskStatus.Failed` state.

   - The behavior may also differ in regards to failure. If an `AggregateException` is thrown when attempting to access the `Result` property when returning from the continuation, then `finalResultTask` may have a doubly-wrapped true inner exception (I'm not sure if a special case occurs here), where the `InnerException` property of `responseTask.Exception` would provide direct access to the actual exception should it fail during the first task.

Comment: Dear downvoters: Please leave a comment so I can work to address your concerns with my question. Sometimes words that make sense to me don't make sense to others, but if you don't tell me which part that was I won't be able to do anything about it. :)

Comment: I also felt that the downvote was unjustified; however, upon reading your code, I assumed it might have been due to your syntax errors (namely, calling `request.GetResponseAsync` instead of `followup.GetResponseAsync` inside the continuation function, and calling the continuation function as `continuation` despite declaring it as `result`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that both your problems would be resolved if you use the [`Unwrap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781129.aspx) extension method. Your goal is to return a new task as a result of your continuation function; however, since the continuation itself *is* executed as a task, this would lead to an extra level of nesting (task returning task). Thus, you need to eliminate this nesting using `Unwrap`, which will give you a proxy task that is bound to the result of the inner task.

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
Task<WebResponse> responseTask = request.GetResponseAsync(cancellationToken);
Func<Task<WebResponse>, Task<WebResponse> continuation =
    task =>
    {
        WebRequest followup = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri2);
        return followup.GetResponseAsync(cancellationToken);
    };

Task<Task<WebResponse>> finalResultTask = responseTask.ContinueWith(continuation);
Task<WebResponse> proxyTask = finalResultTask.Unwrap();
```

Quick optimization: Since your continuation function does little other than spawn off a new task through `GetResponseAsync`, you can reduce its execution overhead by specifying it as `ExecuteSynchronously`:

```
Task<Task<WebResponse>> finalResultTask = responseTask.ContinueWith(continuation, 
    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```

**Edit**: Per Servy's suggestion, you should pass your `CancellationToken` to your continuation function too:

```
Task<Task<WebResponse>> finalResultTask = responseTask.ContinueWith(continuation, 
    cancellationToken,
    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
    TaskScheduler.Current);
```

Comment: Do you have any additional documentation regarding the behavior of the returned proxy task when the continuation enters the `Canceled` or `Failed` states? My intuition is that this covers my needs exactly, but it would be nice to see it stated explicitly in the documentation.

Comment: @280Z28 You'd need to pass the cancellation token to the continuewith call.  Other than that the end task should be in a cancelled state regardless of where in the process the cancellation happens.  You experimentally determine that simply enough as well by throwing in a bunch of Sleep calls and cancelling in the appropriate windows.

Comment: @280Z28: It might be easier to decompile the .NET assemblies rather than look up reference documentation. I ran into some incompatibilities between .NET and Mono on a related function (`ContinueWhenAll`) that were undocumented. And Servy is of course right; you should pass the cancellation token to your continuation task.