# ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(CancellationToken.WaitHandle): will it ever finish?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, cancellation, cancellation-token

I am implementing code from the accepted answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494502/implementing-extension-method-webrequest-getresponseasync-with-support-for-cance/). Now I'm having a  problem looking like threads are being left open: the application never finishes.

I think this may be caused by the bottom one of the two occurences of `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` below. The first one listens for the WebRequest to finish or for the timeout to occur. The second one listens to a Cancellation being requested. Now I'm wondering: does the second one ever finish if no cancellation is requested or will it keep waiting forever?

```
public static Task<WebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this WebRequest request, CancellationToken token)
{
    if (request == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

    bool timeout = false;
    TaskCompletionSource<WebResponse> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<WebResponse>();

    AsyncCallback completedCallback =
        result =>
        {
            try
            {
                completionSource.TrySetResult(request.EndGetResponse(result));
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (timeout)
                    completionSource.TrySetException(new WebException("No response was received during the time-out period for a request.", WebExceptionStatus.Timeout));
                else if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    completionSource.TrySetCanceled();
                else
                    completionSource.TrySetException(ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                completionSource.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        };

    IAsyncResult asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(completedCallback, null);
    if (!asyncResult.IsCompleted)
    {
        if (request.Timeout != Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            WaitOrTimerCallback timedOutCallback =
                (object state, bool timedOut) =>
                {
                    if (timedOut)
                    {
                        timeout = true;
                        request.Abort();
                    }
                };

            ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle, timedOutCallback, null, request.Timeout, true);
        }

        if (token != CancellationToken.None)
        {
            WaitOrTimerCallback cancelledCallback =
                (object state, bool timedOut) =>
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        request.Abort();
                };

            ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(token.WaitHandle, cancelledCallback, null, Timeout.Infinite, true);
        }
    }

    return completionSource.Task;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the thread pool will wait for the Cancellation Token's wait handle to be signaled indefinitely.

You need to save the return value of `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` in order to cancel the outstanding wait operation. See [ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9f75h7a.aspx) Remarks section as it indicates you should always unregister waits.

The outstanding wait operation should not keep your process alive though.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me solving the issue. Actually it kept the process alive. Maybe because i'm using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com).