# Http POST using Task.FromAsync with async request and async response

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have to send an async POST to a web service and I want to send/retrieve the data asynchronously.

I also need to send the request but only wait a maximum of 1500 ms waiting for a response.  If I don't get a response, the program should continue on (this is a service making an external web service call).  I want to offload these service calls to IOCP's instead of blocking for a long time and waiting for them to return.  I only want to block for 1500 ms total.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"urltoPostTo");

            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test-post");
            httpRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            var asyncTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpRequest.BeginGetRequestStream, httpRequest.EndGetRequestStream, httpRequest)
                .ContinueWith(response =>
                {
                    var localStream = response.Result;
                    if (localStream != null)
                    {
                        localStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                        localStream.Close();
                    }
                });  //how do I do the continuation for BeginGetResponse and EndGetResponse from here?
```

I have a couple of requirements that unfortunately I can't change.

1. I am using Visual Studio 2010 targeting 4.0
2. I cannot use the Async BCL
3. I would like to try and use Task.FromAsync

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered in [Implementing extension method WebRequest.GetResponseAsync with support for CancellationToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494502/implementing-extension-method-webrequest-getresponseasync-with-support-for-cance) with a `GetResponseAsync` extension method that properly handles timeouts and CancellationTokens. When Request.Timeout expires, the method calls `Request.Abort` before returning the Task in its cancelled state.

The reason for such involved coding is that it's the client's (yours) responsibility to properly handle timeouts, so you can't depend on FromAsync to handle the timeout expiration. Perhaps this is the reason why FromAsync doesn't accept a cancellation token.

Another option is to avoid cancelling the request itself and cancel the continuation. You can use the [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783219%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload that accepts a CancellationToken and call [CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194678%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set the cancellation timeout.

This would allow your code to ignore the results and keep running but it wouldn't break the connection to the server and wouldn't stop the background thread from processing any potentially expensive results.

You could write something like this:

```
var tcs=new CancellationTokenSource();
var asyncTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpRequest.BeginGetRequestStream, httpRequest.EndGetRequestStream, httpRequest)
.ContinueWith(response =>
{...},
cts.Token);  
cts.CancelAfter(1500);
```

Note that the call to CancelAfter is done after starting the asynchronous task.

I would prefer Reed Copsey's extension method in a busy site because a high number of cancelled but outstanding requests can easily exhaust the thread pool, consume a lot of memory without a reason and consume potentially expensive connections to external systems.

Comment: Is it APPLICABLE with asp.net ? ( 2010 , 4.5) ? I mean - that the main request thread wont be responded to the client while there is a task doing a job...

Answer (score 0):

why not to work with HttpClient?

```
webApiHttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(GetFullAPI("api/Subscribe"), obj)
            .ContinueWith(res => _logger.InfoFormat("Subscribe result: {0}", res.Result.StatusCode));
```

Comment: The OP is targeting 4.0. There is no HttpClient in 4.0. Besides, PostAsJsonAsync is part of ASP.NET Web API

Comment: HttpClient is part of the 4.0 you can take it from nuget and also the postjson is part of newtonsoft - all this package can be downloaded from nuget

Comment: HttpClient is not part of 4.0. It is [a separate package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) that is NOT supported under Visual Studio 2010: *This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010 ...*

Answer (score 0):

Try this method helper.

```
public static Task<string> Post(string url, Encoding encoding, string content)
            {
                var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpRequest.Method = "POST";
                byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(content);
                httpRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

                TaskCompletionSource<string> result = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();


                Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpRequest.BeginGetRequestStream, httpRequest.EndGetRequestStream, httpRequest)
                   .ContinueWith(requestStreamTask =>
                   {
                       try
                       {
                           using (var localStream = requestStreamTask.Result)
                           {
                               localStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                               localStream.Flush();
                           }

                           Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(httpRequest.BeginGetResponse, httpRequest.EndGetResponse, httpRequest)
                               .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
                               {
                                   try
                                   {
                                       using (var webResponse = responseTask.Result)
                                       using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                                       using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream, encoding))
                                       {
                                           result.SetResult(sr.ReadToEnd());
                                       }
                                   }
                                   catch (Exception e)
                                   {
                                       result.SetException(e);
                                   }
                               }, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                       }
                       catch (Exception e)
                       {
                           result.SetException(e);
                       }

                   }, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

                return result.Task;
            }
```